# Beginner about async/Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Have a look at this code:

```
private async void Lista()
{
    var _folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var file = await _folder.GetFileAsync("thefile.txt");
    var read = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
}
```

Since the codeblock contais `await` i need to use `async` in the signature. This means that I cant simply add "`Retrun read`" at the end. (which is what i would like to get back from the method.)

From what I can understand i need to use task somehow. Any tips on how to retrieve the `var read`?

Comment: As an aside `async void` is specifically to allow async event handlers, an async equivalent for a normal void method would return  `Task`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your return type to `Task` of `T` where `T` is your intended return type, in this case `string`.

```
private async Task<string> Lista()
{
    var _folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var file = await _folder.GetFileAsync("thefile.txt");
    var read = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
    return read;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can change the returns type as `Task<string>`

```
private async Task<string> Lista()
{
     var _folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
     var file = await _folder.GetFileAsync("thefile.txt");
     var read = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
     return read;
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/hh156513.aspx)

> An async method can have a return type of `Task`, `Task<TResult>`, or `void`. [...]
>   You specify `Task<TResult>` as the return type of an async method if the return statement of the method specifies an operand of type TResult. You use Task if no meaningful value is returned when the method is completed. That is, a call to the method returns a Task, but when the Task is completed, any await expression that's awaiting the Task evaluates to void.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your return method signature to

```
private async Task<T> Lista()
```

Where `T` is the type returned by `ReadTextAsync` method then you should be able to return it.
It will then have to be awaited by the invoking method. Or the invoking method will have to "unwrap" it using `.Result`.

So assuming that `ReadTextAsync` returns `string` you can try something like that:

```
    private async Task<string> Lista()
    {
        var _folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var file = await _folder.GetFileAsync("thefile.txt");
        return await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
    }
```